# Retrieve records from mysql that have same value for particular column

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a table `Student` with two columns

1)`roll`

2) `marks`

Now I want to retrieve the mark if it is same for all roll's that are supplied as an argument

How can achieve this with a single query on `MySQL`?

The roll list is stored in `php array` variable `$intRolls`

Answer (score 1):

Here `(1,2,3,4,5)` you have to pass as `Array`.Check [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01351/2) here

```
SELECT
  marks
FROM students
WHERE roll IN(1,2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY marks
HAVING COUNT( * ) = (SELECT
                       COUNT(DISTINCT roll)
                     FROM students
                     WHERE roll IN(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Answer (score 1):

What should the query return if there are different marks? This one will return NULL in this case:

```
SELECT IF( COUNT(mark) > 1, NULL, mark) AS processed_mark
FROM students
WHERE roll IN (coma-separated-list-of-rolls-here)
GROUP BY mark;
```

Comment: Yup, replace semicolons by simple comas, sorry about that.